# iPhone Transmitting CoreLocation over the Internet

Tags: objective-c, iphone, gps, core-location

Alrighty, let's try this again!

I'm currently developing an application that will be relying on a web server for some of its functionality. I'm interested, however, in transmitting the user's location to other users who request it. What would be the best possible way to implement this in the application? Thank you! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were making this application for a standard linux server, I would have a MySQL table called locations, or users. Inside that table, I would store the device id, the latitude, longitude, and date of the users' location. Then, when a user's location changes, update the entry in the table using a HTTP request to a PHP script.

As far as the programming, look into NSURLRequests and NSURLConnections. You would need to do a POST or GET, including this information. This might be an example of the requests:

```
{ /* Update Location: http://hostname/path/location.php */
  action = "updatelocation",
  deviceid = "635262f796d3fe35229275d5835bf42861c33f23",
  latitude = 0,
  longitude = 0
}
```

Processing on the server wouldn't be too hard. That should at least get you started on storing the locations. Letting other users request the locations would be a little harder.

Comment: Cool! Well, basically the server functions as a bridge between the two iPhones that have the App running on them. So, given that, will this be enough to get me started in that direction? Thanks! :D

Comment: That should be enough to get you started, as far as storing locations. I'm not sure how I'd handle sharing of locations, but I'm pretty sure I would include the use of push notifications in the background, and asynchronous requests when it's open.

Comment: Well, here's what I've come up with so far. I need to output a file containing the "ID Number" and "Location" so that they can be pulled back in when the user presses a button. For example, somebody needs to know the location of a specific agent, so they press the button for that "ID Number". The button then executes a fetch request to find the file relating to that IDNumber and bring the location file back into the app so it can be used inside of Google Maps. I've written standard NSURLRequests in XCode, but I would like to get a second opinion. Thanks! :D

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. I could use two php scripts to execute the actions. Those scripts would be called via NSURLRequests and assigned variables according to the needs of the GET/POST request. That sound right?